# Swift Compiler Error : Use of undeclared type 'EKEventStore'

Tags: xcode, swift, ios8

In swift, I define a class FirstViewController: UIViewController. At the beginning of the file, I have this imports :

```
import UIKit
import EventKit
```

In a method of the class, I have this line:

```
var eventStore : EKEventStore = EKEventStore()
```

I have imported the `EventKit.framework`.

But I have always this Swift Compiler Error : Use of undeclared type 'EKEventStore'.

Please help!

Comment: I can't reproduce. Just importing EventKit and your other line of code to create an instance of EKEventStore work fine for OS X and iOS 8 here. Is the import line written in the correct file?

Comment: You need to show the actual code that you're using.

Answer (score 3):

You may be drag and Drop Frameworks for your Project.

You must not do like this.

Add frameworks : Targets > BuildPhases > Linked Binary and Libraries > And Click + button and Add frameworks like this.

then you Import. It will work.

other option can you try to import EKEventStore Directly.

Example : `import EKEventStore`

Answer (score 3):

With Deployment Target = 8.0, I have to import the EventKitUI.framework and the Swift Compiler Error disappears. So the header of my class FirstViewController: UIViewController is now :

```
import UIKit
import EventKit
import EventKitUI
```

Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed something : if I change the deployment target from 8.0 to 7.1, the error disappears.
I don't understand why.

Comment: A rough guess to why: Xcode may include a different (larger) set of Swift libraries in the app bundle when deploying for "legacy" systems. And since this is (currently) all beta, the different set of embedded code somehow doesn't have the bug.